# Is uniqueidentifier column in table in MS SQL can be used in Transactional replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

This is a ReportServer from SRSS, it has custom default value that we can't change, and some of our teams need it to be replicated to other server.

I really curious, because I can't find this in any documentation from Microsoft. so long story short, I have a lot of table that has uniqueidentifier in SQL Server 2021 Database, and replicate it to another server using Transactional replication.

The problem is, when the replication take the replication file from unc, and run it into the slave/worker/backup Server, it will reach error because of the SP generated by replication using newsequentialid() function on it's own replication file.. which I really can't find why it even generate that SP for insert...

the error is

```
The newsequentialid() built-in function can only be used in a DEFAULT expression for a column of type 'uniqueidentifier' in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement. It cannot be combined with other operators to form a complex scalar expression. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 302)
```

It's not SP that we generate but SQL Server replication service. So does transactional replication from SQL Server even support any table that have uniqueidentifier column?

The database can be replicated using snapshot replication... but it do take time because the DB is very very big...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT :
It has default value newsequentalid() on it's default value, seems cause to broke the sp generated by the Transactional snapshot.
[image: The example table with default value newsequentalid() cause error on transactional replication]

Example of broken table .sch content

```
drop Table [dbo].[Segment]
go
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Segment](
    [SegmentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Content] [varbinary](max) NULL
)

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

go

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

go

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

go

if object_id(N'[sp_MSins_dboSegment]', 'P') > 0
    drop proc [sp_MSins_dboSegment]
go
if object_id(N'dbo.MSreplication_objects') is not null
    delete from dbo.MSreplication_objects where object_name = N'sp_MSins_dboSegment'
go
create procedure [sp_MSins_dboSegment]
    @c1 uniqueidentifier,
    @c2 varbinary(max)
as
begin  
    insert into [dbo].[Segment] (
        [SegmentId],
        [Content]
    ) values (
        @c1,
        @c2 ) 
end  
go
if columnproperty(object_id(N'dbo.MSreplication_objects'), N'article', 'AllowsNull') is not null
exec sp_executesql 
    @statement = 
        N'insert dbo.MSreplication_objects (object_name, publisher, publisher_db, publication, article, object_type) 
            values 
        (@object_name, @publisher, @publisher_db, @publication, @article, ''P'')',
    @parameters = 
        N'@object_name sysname, @publisher sysname, @publisher_db sysname, @publication sysname, @article sysname',
    @object_name = N'sp_MSins_dboSegment',
    @publisher = N'WIN-GC9CUPIP41I',
    @publisher_db = N'ReportServer',
    @publication = N'ReportTransPub',
    @article = N'Segment'
go
if object_id(N'[dbo].[sp_MSins_dboSegment_msrepl_ccs]', 'P') > 0
    drop proc [dbo].[sp_MSins_dboSegment_msrepl_ccs]
go
create procedure [dbo].[sp_MSins_dboSegment_msrepl_ccs]
        @c1 uniqueidentifier,
        @c2 varbinary(max)
as
begin
if exists (select * 
             from [dbo].[Segment]
            where [SegmentId] = @c1)
begin
update [dbo].[Segment] set
        [Content] = @c2
    where [SegmentId] = @c1
end
else
begin
    insert into [dbo].[Segment] (
        [SegmentId],
        [Content]
    ) values (
        @c1,
        @c2 ) 
end
end
go
if object_id(N'[sp_MSupd_dboSegment]', 'P') > 0
    drop proc [sp_MSupd_dboSegment]
go
if object_id(N'dbo.MSreplication_objects') is not null
    delete from dbo.MSreplication_objects where object_name = N'sp_MSupd_dboSegment'
go
create procedure [sp_MSupd_dboSegment]
        @c1 uniqueidentifier = NULL,
        @c2 varbinary(max) = NULL,
        @pkc1 uniqueidentifier = NULL,
        @bitmap binary(1)
as
begin  
    declare @primarykey_text nvarchar(100) = ''
if (substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 1 = 1)
begin 
if @pkc1 is null
     set @pkc1 = (newsequentialid())
update [dbo].[Segment] set
        [SegmentId] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 1 when 1 then @c1 else [SegmentId] end,
        [Content] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 2 when 2 then @c2 else [Content] end
    where [SegmentId] = @pkc1
if @@rowcount = 0
    if @@microsoftversion>0x07320000
        Begin
            if exists (Select * from sys.all_parameters where object_id = OBJECT_ID('sp_MSreplraiserror') and [name] = '@param3')
            Begin
                
                set @primarykey_text = @primarykey_text + '[SegmentId] = ' + convert(nvarchar(100),@pkc1,1)
                exec sp_MSreplraiserror @errorid=20598, @param1=N'[dbo].[Segment]', @param2=@primarykey_text, @param3=13233 
            End
            Else
                exec sp_MSreplraiserror @errorid=20598
        End
end  
else
begin 
if @pkc1 is null
     set @pkc1 = (newsequentialid())
update [dbo].[Segment] set
        [Content] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 2 when 2 then @c2 else [Content] end
    where [SegmentId] = @pkc1
if @@rowcount = 0
    if @@microsoftversion>0x07320000
        Begin
            if exists (Select * from sys.all_parameters where object_id = OBJECT_ID('sp_MSreplraiserror') and [name] = '@param3')
            Begin
                
                set @primarykey_text = @primarykey_text + '[SegmentId] = ' + convert(nvarchar(100),@pkc1,1)
                exec sp_MSreplraiserror @errorid=20598, @param1=N'[dbo].[Segment]', @param2=@primarykey_text, @param3=13233 
            End
            Else
                exec sp_MSreplraiserror @errorid=20598
        End
end 
end 
go
if columnproperty(object_id(N'dbo.MSreplication_objects'), N'article', 'AllowsNull') is not null
exec sp_executesql 
    @statement = 
        N'insert dbo.MSreplication_objects (object_name, publisher, publisher_db, publication, article, object_type) 
            values 
        (@object_name, @publisher, @publisher_db, @publication, @article, ''P'')',
    @parameters = 
        N'@object_name sysname, @publisher sysname, @publisher_db sysname, @publication sysname, @article sysname',
    @object_name = N'sp_MSupd_dboSegment',
    @publisher = N'WIN-GC9CUPIP41I',
    @publisher_db = N'ReportServer',
    @publication = N'ReportTransPub',
    @article = N'Segment'
go
if object_id(N'[sp_MSdel_dboSegment]', 'P') > 0
    drop proc [sp_MSdel_dboSegment]
go
if object_id(N'dbo.MSreplication_objects') is not null
    delete from dbo.MSreplication_objects where object_name = N'sp_MSdel_dboSegment'
go
create procedure [sp_MSdel_dboSegment]
        @pkc1 uniqueidentifier
as
begin  
if @pkc1 is null
     set @pkc1 = (newsequentialid())
    declare @primarykey_text nvarchar(100) = ''
    delete [dbo].[Segment] 
    where [SegmentId] = @pkc1
if @@rowcount = 0
    if @@microsoftversion>0x07320000
        Begin
            if exists (Select * from sys.all_parameters where object_id = OBJECT_ID('sp_MSreplraiserror') and [name] = '@param3')
            Begin
                
                set @primarykey_text = @primarykey_text + '[SegmentId] = ' + convert(nvarchar(100),@pkc1,1)
                exec sp_MSreplraiserror @errorid=20598, @param1=N'[dbo].[Segment]', @param2=@primarykey_text, @param3=13234 
            End
            Else
                exec sp_MSreplraiserror @errorid=20598
        End
end  
go
if columnproperty(object_id(N'dbo.MSreplication_objects'), N'article', 'AllowsNull') is not null
exec sp_executesql 
    @statement = 
        N'insert dbo.MSreplication_objects (object_name, publisher, publisher_db, publication, article, object_type) 
            values 
        (@object_name, @publisher, @publisher_db, @publication, @article, ''P'')',
    @parameters = 
        N'@object_name sysname, @publisher sysname, @publisher_db sysname, @publication sysname, @article sysname',
    @object_name = N'sp_MSdel_dboSegment',
    @publisher = N'WIN-GC9CUPIP41I',
    @publisher_db = N'ReportServer',
    @publication = N'ReportTransPub',
    @article = N'Segment'
go
if object_id(N'[dbo].[sp_MSdel_dboSegment_msrepl_ccs]', 'P') > 0
    drop proc [dbo].[sp_MSdel_dboSegment_msrepl_ccs]
go
create procedure [dbo].[sp_MSdel_dboSegment_msrepl_ccs]
        @pkc1 uniqueidentifier
as
begin  
if @pkc1 is null
     set @pkc1 = (newsequentialid())
    declare @primarykey_text nvarchar(100) = ''
    delete [dbo].[Segment] 
    where [SegmentId] = @pkc1
end  
go
```

Comment: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is a supported data type of a replicated column in a Transactional Replication topology. It sounds like your schemas between the Publisher and Subscriber might be out of wack somehow. We'd need more details to help you troubleshoot, such as the definition of the table from the Publisher and Subscriber side, and the procedure definition you're saying replication generated. Please add this information to your Post.

Comment: @J.D. Thanks for replying! Can you guide me a bit better about "schemas" things? So there are a simple table, that has uniqueidentifier as primary key, but not allowed to be null (obviously), have no default value. When I publish the table using replication, it's fine, but the subscriber are syncing it (pulling method), it will fail because on the .sch and other generated syncing file, it generate an stored procedure that use newsequentialid() function. I will try to add the procedure on the question. Thank you for replying.

Comment: @J.D. I add some additional data, could you please look into it? Thank you

Comment: "*Can you guide me a bit better about "schemas" things?*" - Schema is the structure of your database. For example, the structure of your `dbo.Segment` table, which you've provided. Now that I know the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is the primary key, and has a default set, that changes the question a little bit. I'll have to do some research and will get back to you. Do you have access to create new objects in the Publisher database?

Comment: ah.... I think you are talking about something else. I want try it to another instance, I don't know why they are having problem with that function tbh... when replicating.

Comment: It sounds more likely the function being used in the `DEFAULT` specification is the problem, and not really related to the fact that the primary key is a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`. But do you have access to make changes to the Publisher database?

Comment: @J.D. I can make suggestion based on that. I do know that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 Can't be used not other than table...

Comment: Well anyway, if you're able to create objects in the Publisher database, and you don't want to modify the source table, you can create an indexed view on top of it instead and replicate that indexed view to a table on the Subscriber side. I would guess that would solve your problem.

Comment: @J.D. Uhm. Isn't indexed. View still need the main table to be published?

Comment: An [Indexed View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16) is different than a regular View and doesn't need the table to be Published.

Comment: @J.D. After talk with my colleague, seems it's imposible, because it's a database that created by SQL Report server, and we want to replicate it across server, but seems we can't change any of it, as the folk use it as is.

Comment: It's the SSRS database, `ReportServer`?

Comment: @J.D. Yes, is there anyway to replicate it. I never use ReportServer so... this is first time I knew it

Comment: Why would you want to replicate it?...it doesn't have much useful information in it.

Comment: Dunno, they seems adamant to replicate it. I try to say If they can't alter it, then we can't do anything to make it works for replication. So in short it isn't possible right?

Comment: Nothing's impossible, but seems silly to replicate it. It can be accessed directly from another server through a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) too.

Comment: @J.D. They want to have backup, that's what they said. haha... What can I say then... We do can have dump, but that takes time.

Comment: Ah ok. For what it's worth, Replication is not officially a disaster recovery solution. It's possible for a change to be made in the Publisher database, and then the server goes down before that change gets replicated to the Subscriber database, resulting in the Subscriber database being out dated. Also if you guys use Report Subscriptions, they won't replicate ever. They are executed by SQL Agent Jobs which live in the `msdb` database. Honestly, having a useable backup of the SSRS database will be a lot of work. If you guys have Enterprise Edition of SQL Server, you could look into using...

Comment: ...Availability Groups which is a true disaster recovery solution. But you'd still have to create / maintain the Report Schedule SQL Agent Jobs on the secondary server either way, and only enable them when the secondary server becomes the primary.

Comment: @J.D. I think the comments now become the answer. I will update my question, please do create an answer, and I will set it as the answer so others can see it. Thank you.